# Getting response after 2mins in HttpClient postAbs Vert.x

Tags: websocket, java-8, httpclient, vert.x

I'm listening to Eventbus as below and calling HttpClient.postAbs() using vert.x

```
 public void start(Future<Void> fut) {
    EventBus eb1 = MainAdminVx.serviceBack.getEventBus();
    eb1.consumer("local-message-receiver", message -> {

         HttpClient client = vertx.createHttpClient();

         client.postAbs("http://external-server-address/test@xyz.com/activityIn?activityId=5", r -> {
             r.bodyHandler(b -> System.out.println(b.toString() +  r.statusCode() )
                      ).exceptionHandler(t -> System.err.println(t.getMessage()));
            })
              .putHeader("content-length", "1000")
              .putHeader("userId", "test@xyz.com")
              .putHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
              .putHeader("Accept", "application/json")
              .write("some text")
              .exceptionHandler(System.err::println)
              .end();


    });

}
```

Is there anything I'm missing? or there is another way to do this... because I'm getting response after 2mins in postAbs and same POST request is working quickly in postman .

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just have to set

> setChunked(true)

and it works like a charm !!!

> As I have set content-length as '1000' , so server will wait until it receives 1000 bytes even though your not sending anything and respond back after. It means the exact byte length of the HTTP body. Generally it is used for HTTP 1.1 so that the receiving party knows when the current response/request has finished, so the connection can be reused for another request.

So what is Chunked transfer :

> Chunked transfer encoding is a data transfer mechanism in version 1.1 of the Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP) in which data is sent in a series of "chunks". It uses the Transfer-Encoding HTTP header in place of the Content-Length header, which the earlier version of the protocol would otherwise require. Because the Content-Length header is not used, the sender does not need to know the length of the content before it starts transmitting a response to the receiver. Senders can begin transmitting dynamically-generated content before knowing the total size of that content.

Alternatively, content-length can be omitted and a chunked encoding can be used, or if both are missing, then at the end of the response the connection must be closed.

I hope this will help you to understand Http chunk concept.